# php get data on IE (Greek char) does not work

Tags: php, internet-explorer, encoding, get

I have two pages and I use AJAX in order to do some tasks without refreshing the page.
The problem is when I use Internet Explorer, I got the value as '?'. What I try to do is to have a catalog and when a user clicks on a character, the other page is performing SQL tasks and the first page presents the results.

First page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(myLink)
{
alert ("OK");
var xmlhttp;
alert (myLink);
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }    
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }      
xmlhttp.open("GET","select.php?data=" + myLink,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<center>
<font size = "4">     
 <a href = "#" onClick = "loadXMLDoc('Ι'); return false;">Ι </a>      
 </font>
</center>    
<div id = "information">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The second page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
//var_dump($_GET);
//exit();
session_start();
$find = $_GET["data"];
$find = iconv("utf8", "utf8", $find);
echo "New find = " . $find;
$find = iconv("utf8", "utf8", "Ι"); //Greek character
echo "<br/>Newest find = " . $find;
?>
```

The first 'echo' will print a questionmark ('?') while the second one will print the proper character. That problem appears only on Internet Explorer, it works on any other.
If I use the 'var_dump', I get:

> Internet Explorer: array(1) { ["data"]=> string(1) "?" }
>
> Chrome and Mozilla: array(1) { ["data"]=> string(2) "Ι" }

No problem at all with AJAX.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to avoid this kind of problem is to actually use HTML entities for all special characters.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

So if you want an alpha, use 
       &#913; 
rather than just paste an alpha in your code.  If you're loading text from a database, however, that would require looking at the character codes and converting to entities.  But its easy enough because the HTML entity will always work as ampersand followed by pound sign then character code value then a semicolon.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. I tried it but it does not work:
I changed to:
    onClick = "loadXMLDoc('&#913;'); return false;"

Comment: That won't work.  You should change the code that displays the character in your PHP page, not the code that sends it as a parameter to your PHP page via Ajax. Unless you change the database and everything to consistently use the HTML entity.  PHP will not magically convert the HTML entity back to UTF8 before querying the database.

Comment: I do not know if I understood what you said, but how I can change a non-hardcoded value? I want something dynamic, for instance how I can distinguish between two characters (i.e. A, I) if I hardcode them and not pass them from the first page?